# UniswapV2 pairFor gives wrong contract address

Tags: solidity, uniswap

When i try to add liquidity function fails because `pairFor` returns wrong pair address
original code (not working on ganache, hardhat and testnets)

```
        (address token0, address token1) = sortTokens(tokenA, tokenB);
        pair = address(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
                hex'ff',
                factory,
                keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)),
                hex'96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f' // init code hash
            ))));
    }
```

found some similar issues on stackoverflow and they suggested changing init code hash
therefore i used `bytes32 public constant INIT_CODE_PAIR_HASH = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode))`

and it still doesn't work

My modified code with new init hash

````
        (address token0, address token1) = sortTokens(tokenA, tokenB);
        pair = address(uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
                hex'ff',
                factory,
                keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)),
                '0x932b4f40ffd7547443affda5e84a39f3efc69f2ca17d46f0f9427e015f0fb178' // init code hash
            ))));
    }```
````